# Calling callbacks across processes causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, process, callback

Two separate programs use a common lib that allows them to:

- register a callback for a given event (events are enum values I created)
- signal an event, thus calling all callbacks connected to this event.

My test case is:

- in program B, register the local function `my_callback()` to event 1,
- in program A, signal event 1.

I have verified that:

- program B registers its callback to the correct event, and connects a seemingly reasonable pointer to the callback (`0x400d80`)
- program A upon signaling event 1 finds B's callback, with the correct address (`0x400d80`).

What happens upon trying to actually run B's callback from A is Segmentation fault.

Isn't it possible to call B's callback from A, even if these are separate processes? It feels like A is complaining about trying to run something in someone else's sandbox.

How do I make program A call to a function in B?

---

Here is the code to call all callbacks associated to a given event (in the lib's `signal()`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < event_list[event].nb_callbacks; ++i) {
    printf("callback %d address: %p\n", i, event_list[event].callbacks[i]);
    if (event_list[event].callbacks[i] != NULL) {
        event_list[event].callbacks[i]();
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: registered callback is NULL\n");
    }
}
```

Here is how I register the callback address (program B):

```
static bool event_occured = false;
void on_signal_input(void);

int main()
{
    // ...
    if (event_register(evd, EVENT_TEST_1, on_signal_input) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: event_register\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // ...
}

void on_signal_input(void)
{
    printf("event occured\n");
    event_occured = true;
}
```

Comment: It's likely `0x400d80` makes no sense in A's address space. Post some code?

Comment: Yes, that's my guess as well. So the question is how to pass a function address that would make sense, upon `register`? I added some code, although I think the question is just that. I need some kind of function pointer that makes sense globally.

Comment: The segmentation fault is caused because the address `0x400d80` of the callback in process B is **not** globally accessable. It is only accessable from within B. process A has also a address   `0x400d80` **but** it points to something within the process A and is either not executable for A or not the beginning of a function.

Comment: @SebastianStigler: is there a way to get a function pointer that would be globally accessible?

Comment: @Gauthier, are you looking for [IPC:Shared Memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html)?

Comment: @AlterMann: I am not sure what you mean. The list of callback addresses is saved in shared memory (so that several other processes may use the common even/callback list), but the callback addresses are still to the registering process's virtual address space, whatever if they are stored in shm or not.

Comment: calling a method which belongs to process A from process B requires a inter-process communication mechanism. Calling the method directly I don't think is possible but you can use a socket to tell Process B to execute the method you want. Not the same thing but it works.